# How to make Bootstrap Tab dynamic PHP?

Tags: php

I have a problem for making TAB dynamically. When I click Tab 2 (when `class="tab-pane fade"`), a tab content was duplicated from Tab 1 and so do to another tab.This is a screenshot [image]

And this is my php code :

```
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM pur_supp WHERE pn = '$id_p' and pn_interchange = '$id_a'";
            $hasil1= mysqli_query($connect2,$sql1);
            //$rowp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil1);

            $tab_menu = '';
$tab_content = '';
$i = 0;
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil1))
{
 if($i == 0)
 {
  $tab_menu .= '
   <li class="active"><a href="#priority'.$row1["priority"].'" data-toggle="tab">Priority '.$row1["priority"].'</a></li>
  ';
  $tab_content .= '
   <div id="priority'.$row1["priority"].'" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  ';
 }
 else
 {
  $tab_menu .= '
   <li><a href="#priority'.$row1["priority"].'" data-toggle="tab">Priority '.$row1["priority"].'</a></li>
  ';
  $tab_content .= '
   <div id="priority'.$row1["priority"].'" class="tab-pane fade">
  ';
 }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pur_supp WHERE pn = '$id_p' and pn_interchange = '$id_a' and priority = '".$row1["priority"]."' GROUP BY pn,pn_interchange";
            $hasil2= mysqli_query($connect2,$sql2);     
    while($rowp = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil2))
    {
        $tab_content .= '<div class="panel-heading" align="center">';

        $tab_content .= '<h2 >Selected Vendor Information</h2>';
        $tab_content .= '<div class="panel-heading" align="center">';
        $tab_content .= '<h5 >PURCHASE SUPPLIER</h5>';
        $tab_content .= '<p style="font-weight: bold">Part Number';
        $tab_content .= '<input style="text-align:center;margin-left: 90px" class="form-control" type="text" name="pn1" value="'. $rowp['pn'].'" readonly>  </p>';
        $tab_content .= ' <p style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left">Selected Vendor Information : Priority '.$rowp['priority'].'</p>';

    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: from the looks of this loop you are not closing your divs.

Comment: @joeycrash135, can you show me about that code for closing div ?

Comment: `$tab_content .= '<div class="panel-heading" align="center">';`
    `$tab_content .= 'my content';`
    `$tab_content .= '</div>';`

Comment: @joeycrash135, Thank you for your suggest. there are a double of `$tab_content .= '<div class="panel-heading" align="center">';`

Comment: see in your while loop you create the panel-heading divs, but they aren't being closed, so its just turning into 1 big div

Comment: @joeycrash135, Yeah I have been add div..